# USB flash drive keeps activating 'write protection' by itself. Disarms after unsafe removal

Tags: filesystems, usb-flash-drive, hardware-failure, exfat

Drive history

> My 16gb Kingston USB flash drive has been consistently giving
>   problems.  Under Windows XP it kept saying 'This storage media is
>   write protected' after copying over approximately 7 gigabytes worth of
>   files.  At first I thought this meant that one of the NAND chips are
>   not functioning properly(since it's only taking half the full
>   capacity), since the USB has two on either side.
>
> I used to use the USB quite frequently as a bootable USB drive for
>   video editing, meaning that it got several gigabytes worth of data
>   written to it on a *daily* basis.

However, now I am on Windows 8, using it as a backup disk. It is repeatedly throwing "0x8000FFFF Catastrophic Failure" messages at Windows when I try to create a file after writing 128mb of data on it.
Plugging the usb drive back in will allow another 128mb of data before it locks up again.

**Error preview:**

[image]

**Trying to scan drive for errors:**

[image]

**Trying again to scan drive for errors, after unsafe removal:**

[image]

Is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: First question: did this drive EVER work correctly? Or has it always had issues? Because if it's always had issues, I'd say it's defective and/or fake. Otherwise, try re-formatting it, then try to scan again. If it still fails, throw it out, it's gone bad.

Comment: It's broken. :) You can get a brand new Kingston 16GB flash drive that supports USB3 for <US$15.